# django-autocomplete-light choices ordering

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

Is there any best practice to implement fields priority in django-autocomplete-light?

In another words, if I have a class `Cls`, witch contains fields `a` and `b` and I have autocomplete for these fields, then choices, which matches by `a` field should go before fields, which matches `b` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe, there is no better solution than overriding `choices_for_request` method.